# Applying custom stylesheet to QWebView

Tags: css, qt, qwebview

My Qt application loads an external html page within a `QWebView` widget. How can I define my own stylesheet to present the content of the page? Is it possible to bundle a `.css` file for QWebView to pick up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it with the settings of your `QWebView` :

```
QWebView myView;
QWebSettings * settings = myView->settings();
QUrl myCssFileURL;
settings->setUserStyleSheetUrl(myCssFileURL);
```

Comment: What if I want to set multiple CSS files?