# QWebView does not use qss stylesheet scrollbar

Tags: qt, qwebview, qtstylesheets, qt5.5

I have defined a (qss) stylesheet for my Qt widget's scrollbars. It works with my widgets (e.g. `QTableView`) except for `QWebView`.

How can I set the style for a `QWebView` scrollbar?

[Applying custom stylesheet to QWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11297181/356726) explains how to set a css (not qss / Qt stylesheet) for a `QWebView`. Assumption: That would change the content of `QWebView` - not its scrollbars, correct?